# Fetching the next page in the heap table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have been reading about postgres heap tables. The data is inserted in postgres in file named after OID of the table, and the file is split into pages of default size 8KB. I was inspecting the page layout of heap tuple, and no where found the link of page(i) to page(i + 1). Arent heap table pages supposed to be linkedlist. Or if they are implemented like page directory, where this info is stored. During seq scan, how it is inferred that the search is required to move to the next page since there is no such pointer for this.

This is how postgres generic page looks

[Page Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a8TP.png)

And these are the Heap Tuple related data:
[Heap Tuple Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiYe9.png)

I dont see a link of page(i) to page(i + 1).

During a sequential scan:

1. How the buffer manager fetches the next page.
2. How it is inferred that the search need to go to next page now.
3. How it is inferred that search need to go to next file now (since by default, file sizes are of 1GB in postgres)

I have also gone through [Postgres Page Layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html) but no where the above query is mentioned.

Also, in postgres code, the file [heapam.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c), the method

```
heap_getnext
```

exists, but i dont see how internally the buffer manager is able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The pages are stored one after the other in a *file*. To get to the second page, just skip the first 8kB of the file. There is no need for a pointer, you can easily calculate the offset into the file to access a certain page.

If the table contains more than 1GB of data, it is split into segments of 1GB. If `relfilenode` is 12345, these files will be called `12345`, `12345.1`, `12345.2` etc. Each of these segments (except the last one) contains exactly 131072 pages, so it is easy to calculate in which segment a given page will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info.
Although,
1. How the seq scan will jump from one file to another file (in case data is more than 1GB). 
2. Where is this info listed that particular table has 'x' number of pages.

Comment: I have added the explanation to the answer.